# Multiple MainViewControllers Sharing a FlipSideViewController in a Utility App

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there any way for a Utility App to have multiple MainViewControllers sharing the same FlipSideViewController?  I want to be able to make a selection in the FlipSideViewController, and then have one of the other ViewControllers appear on the flip side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it is possible, just make sure that when you are doing the flip transition that you are passing that FlipSideViewController as the flip side in all of View Controllers where you want the FlipSide to be visible...

This is why you want to have a separate VC for each view, so that you can reuse it in multiple locations...

Comment: Thanks for responding.  How would I go about implementing this using Storyboards so that upon flipping away from the FlipSide, an alertnate MainViewController is shown?